# Blog posts - subscribe? Pin to top?

Tags: ee

Is it possible for visitors to subscribe to categories on the EE blog, so they receive email notifications whenever a new blog is posted?

Also, it is possible to "pin" a blog post at the top of either the blog homepage and/or the blog category homepage, so it always shows up at the top of the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Make Sticky" checkbox under "Options". That will promote any entry to the top of the list in a Channel Entries loop.